# Re-organize a list using python with 1 to many relation

Tags: python, list, sorting, loops

I'm trying to organize a list of 'orders' and 'items' obtained from a SQL query.

My python list contains users concerned by orders. 
Each user have 1 or n order(s) and an order can contain 0 or n items.
It looks as follow :

```
information = [
 {'item_id': 2,
  'item_name': 'glass',
  'order_id': 21,
  'uid': 1,
  'uname': 'john'},
 {'item_id': 3,
  'item_name': 'wine',
  'order_id': 21,
  'uid': 1,
  'uname': 'john'},
 {'item_id': 1,
  'item_name': 'napkin',
  'order_id': 12,
  'uid': 1,
  'uname': 'john'},
 {'item_id': 1,
  'item_name': 'napkin',
  'order_id': 12,
  'uid': 2,
  'uname': 'peter'}
 ... etc ...
 ]
```

**What I want to have is :**

```
[{'orders': [{'items': [{'item_id': 2, 'item_name': 'glass'},
                        {'item_id': 3, 'item_name': 'wine'}],
              'order_id': 21},
             {'items': [{'item_id': 1, 'item_name': 'napkin'}],
              'order_id': 12}],
  'uid': 1,
  'uname': 'john'},
 {'uid': 2, 'uname': 'peter'} ... etc ... ]
```

I tried to loop through the first list appending users and orders to a new result list.
But I'm faced with difficulties when I want to update this new list, I don't know how to do it.

Perhaps someone has any clue, or any relevant information to solve this problem ? 
thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to nest things so deeply.  I'd have a dictionary of orders with orderids as keys, a dictionary of items with itemids as keys, and a dictionary of users with userids as keys all separately.  The dictionary key is sort of the Pythonic equivalent of the SQL table key, and it seems to me that there is probably a table for each of those things.  You can put the users and the userorders together if you want somehow....

```
users = {1:'john'}
userorders = {1:[21]}
#goes to a list of item ids ONLY
orders = {21:[2,3]}
items = {2:'glass',3:'wine'}
```

Now all you have to do is append an item to an order and append an order to a user.

So you make an SQL query, get back an order Q:

```
users[Q['uid']] = Q['uname']
userorders[Q['uid']].append(Q['order_id'])
orders[Q['orderid']].append(Q['item_id'])
items[Q['item_id']] = Q['itemname']
```

You can find the items john ordered by:

```
for order in userorders[1]:
  for item in orders[order]:
    print items[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rearrange the items of each dictionary if you iterate over each entry first, and then group the items by `order_id`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# information = [...]
result = {}

for entry in information:
    uid = entry['uid']
    order_id = entry['order_id']
    if not uid in result:
        result[uid] = {'uid': uid, 'uname': entry['uname'], 'orders': defaultdict(list)}

    result[uid]['orders'][order_id].append({
        'item_id': entry['item_id'],
        'item_name': entry['item_name']}
    )

for uid, value in result.iteritems():
    value['orders'] = [{'items': items, 'order_id': order_id} for order_id, items in value['orders'].iteritems()]
```